# Crossing edges at space

Tags: graph-theory

Let's say I have Graph $G(v, e)$ 
I want to draw the graph without crossing edges on space.

By giving $(x, y, z)$ for any Vertex. 
How can I check if one edge crosses another?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "by giving $(x,y,z)$ for any vertex". However if you want to check that there are no edge crossings, you need to show the graph is planar (alternatively, every connected component is planar).

Comment: Dvir:  can you define what you mean by some of these operations? It's hard to understand what you're asking, as-stated.

Comment: my professor argued that:

**"It is known that any graph can be embedded into a three-dimensional space,without crossing edges."**

My first mission for my Final Project is to find proof of claim, and code. Sorry let's say I have Graph, how can I check if the edges is crossing?

Comment: What you are trying to find is graph embedding. See if this helps.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding#Embeddings_of_graphs_into_higher-dimensional_spaces

Answer (score 1):

Put all the vertexes on the first $\vert v\vert$ positive integers of the $x$ axis (so if you have 3 vertexes, they'll be in the coordenates $(1,0,0)$, $(2,0,0)$ and $(3,0,0)$. Then count the amount of edges: $\vert e\vert$.

Now we will draw every edge in a different semiplane, so that no edges cross:

Draw the first edge in the $xz^+$ semiplane. Let's call it $P_0$. Then construct a semiplane, $P_1$ such that $\angle (P_0,P_1) = \frac{2\pi}{\vert e\vert}$ and $P_0 \cap P_1$ is the $x$ axis. Put the second edge in $P_1$.

Construct $P_k$ such that $\angle (P_{k-1},P_k) = \frac{2\pi}{\vert e\vert}$ and  $P_{k-1} \cap P_k$ is the $x$ axis. And put the $(k+1)$-th edge there.

All the edges are in a different semiplane so none of them crosses another one.

Comment: If I add the condition that every edge must be a straight line (not a curve), is it still possible ?

Comment: I don't think so, but it might be...
Try placing the vertexes on the surface of a sphere and draw the edges in it's interior